# Convert double value to List<Int> in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, type-conversion

I'm using flutter_blue to communicate with a bluetooth device. I need to pass a double value to the bluetooth device using the [flutter_blue write() method](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue/latest/flutter_blue/BluetoothCharacteristic/write.html).

The value must be passed to the method as a list of integers which is supposed to represent a list of bytes as far as i understand it.

The flutter_blue write method:

```
Future<Null> write(
   List<int> value,
   {bool withoutResponse = false}
)
```

Is there a way to convert a double value to a list of integers that represents the double value as a list of bytes in order to pass it to flutter_blues write method?

For example:

```
double value = 10.52;
List<Int> convertedValue = someConversionMethod(value);
await bluetoothCharacteristic.write(convertedValue);
```

Comment: So you want the `convertedValue` to be a `List` with just the converted value as element ?

Comment: By passing a `double` as a "list of integers", do you mean a *list of bytes*?  It's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: With Bluetooth it is normal to pass information as a list of bytes(integers). Is it a standard Bluetooth Service that you are trying to pass the values to? Maybe take a look at the [GATT Specification Supplement 4](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) especially section 2 "Values and represented values" as this might help answer some of your questions

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for pointing that out, i'm going to edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

The dart:typed_data library has some useful methods to convert data to bytes. This method worked for me.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

List<int> doubleToListInt(double value) {
  ByteData bytes = ByteData(8);
  bytes.setFloat64(0, value);

  List<int> response =
  bytes.buffer.asInt8List().toList();

  return response;
}

print(doubleToListInt(10.52)); // Returns [64, 37, 10, 61, 112, -93, -41, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bluetooth it is normal to pass information as a list of bytes(Uint8List). The solution for `float` value is to have an expected exponent. There is more detail in the [GATT Specification Supplement 4](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) especially in section 2 "Values and represented values"

If the number is large enough it will need to be converted to bytes in little endian format. As an example:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  double value = 10.52;
  var rawValue = value * pow(10, 2); // multiply value to remove decimal places
  print('Raw value to send: $rawValue'); // Raw value to send 1052
  var sendValue = ByteData(2);
  sendValue.setUint16(0, rawValue.toInt(), Endian.little);
  print('As Uint8List of values: ${sendValue.buffer.asUint8List()}');
  // As Uint8List of values: [28, 4]
}
```